# IServicesConfigurator not found

Tags: sitecore-api, dependency-injection

My Sitecore web application is a .Net Framework 4.8 Web application. I am trying to integrate Sitecore DI container.
I have added Nuget packages for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstraction` and `Sitecore.DependencyInjection`.

I have written `ServicesConfigurator` class looking at example [here](https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/03/24/sitecore-upgrades-a-mini-series-part-5-dependency-injection-changes/). For some reason,
`IServicesConfigurator` is not getting resolved. Please refer to the attached image.

Can anyone please help? Is it because I am using .Net Framework 4.8 Web application? I dont think so.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: close the VS and clean the temp file then open, and build the solution. Make sure dependency injection DLL is added to your project reference. 

and also update your build error in your question.

Comment: @Rameshkumar this is the first thing I tried but didn't work. It got resolved after providing reference of Sitecore.Kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine with.Net Framework 4.8 Web application. It's a reference issue with dlls/version of dll. I think You need to add a Nuget package reference of `Sitecore.Kernel` as per your Sitecore version into the project. `IServicesConfigurator` interface is a part of `Sitecore.DependencyInjection` namespace and part of `Sitecore.Kernel.Dll`.It would install relative dependencies of DI DLLs like below.

[image]

You can remove all the references you added and add `Sitecore.Kernel` from the Nuget package and create `ServicesConfigurator` class.

```
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace XX.Website
{
    public class ServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            //Code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sitecore.Kernel` DLL reference is mandatory to make use of DLL `Sitecore.DependencyInjection`.

[image]

Make sure you have added a compatible reference of DLL `Sitecore.Kernel`.

I am using Sitecore DI with version V 10.2 and the DI is working as expected. The DLL version details are given below,

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0

Sitecore.Kernel, Version=17.0.0.0

.Net Framework, Version=4.8

[image]